# How to operate within.env file?(addition, multiplication)

Tags: javascript, environment-variables

I'm working on proyect with Nodejs. I work with .env file and I came up with a question.

I guees that I can't do this.

My .env file

#time in seconds

```
TOKEN_TIME_LIVE=(60*10)
```

How to operate on an .env file? Through what method can I do?

Sorry the ignorance and thanks for the help.

Comment: Any specific reason why you can't write `600` directly in `.env` file

Comment: It is only an example, what I want to know if you can perform mathematical operations, sorry for the example.

Comment: My apologies. I made a beginner's mistake. I understand the problem you had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `.env` file you can't use mathematical operations and can only store constant values and if you want to change it dynamically than you can change it in your project file by using any user defined function or any other method you can use to change the value of the constant by accessing the variable using `process.env.TOKEN_TIME_LIVE`.

I'm sure it would help solve your question, In case I'm wrong any where please correct me and clear my misconception.